# b2PolygonShape/b2Fixture doubling in size for retina display?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, shapes

Currently I create a b2Fixture like this:

```
b2PolygonShape spriteShape;
    int num = 3;
    b2Vec2 verts[] = {
        b2Vec2(-29.5f / PTM_RATIO, -49.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(10.0f / PTM_RATIO, -49.0f / PTM_RATIO),
        b2Vec2(34.2f / PTM_RATIO, -9.2f / PTM_RATIO),
    };
    spriteShape.Set(verts, num);
    bodyFixture.shape = &spriteShape;
    bodyCharacter->CreateFixture(&bodyFixture);
```

The problem is that on a retina display it seems to double in size, is there a reason for this, and if so how do I make it so that it stays the same size so it doesn't get messed up on any device?

Thanks!

Comment: How are PTM_RATIO, your world and (presumably you are using it) debug draw set up?

Comment: Let me ask you this first, is my PTM_Ratio supposed to be universal for all devices or should it be different?

Comment: Universal - cocos2d and box2d work in points and meters respectively, not pixels.

Comment: Oh ok so then the PTM Ratio should not be the issue. This is how I debug: http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/09/wrapping-box2d-debug-into-a-cocos2d-layer/
And I create my b2World like this: world = new b2World((b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f)), NO);

Comment: What version of cocos2d are you on?

Comment: I think 1.1 but I already solved it from the answerer below :)

Comment: Yeah, that will 'fix' it but the problem is not in the code you are using to make the bodies but somewhere else - this code will cause strange behaviour in the future (e.g half speed objects) in some cases. I know from experience :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue as of yours. I have multiplied the content Scale Factor with PTM_RATIO.

You can try the code as below and check it out... It worked for me

```
int num = 3;
b2Vec2 verts[] = {
    b2Vec2(-29.5f / ( PTM_RATIO * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() ), -49.0f / ( PTM_RATIO * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() )),
    b2Vec2(10.0f / ( PTM_RATIO * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() ), -49.0f / ( PTM_RATIO * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() )),
    b2Vec2(34.2f / ( PTM_RATIO * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() ), -9.2f / ( PTM_RATIO * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() )),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that PTM_RATIO is not multiplied by CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(). See this [article for a number of possible solutions](http://cocos2d-central.com/page/index.html/_/retina-hd/proper-retina-content-scaling-with-box2d-r13).

Comment: So are you saying that I should multiply by that or not? And if not, what would be the solution to my issue?